# How to compare two images but only the drawn rectangle part?

Tags: c#, winforms

Both pictureBox2 and pictureBox3 SizeMode is set to StretchImage !

I draw a rectangle with the mouse on pictureBox2 and i want that the comparison will be between the images in pictureBox2 and pictureBox3 but only inside the drawn rectangle and the result to show on pictureBox1.

inside the method CompositeDifferences i'm looping over the drawn rectangle height and width.

but there is no result on pictureBox1.
I draw a rectangle on pictureBox2 but nothing as result show on pictureBox1 the big pictureBox is pictureBox1 :

[image: drawn rectangle the comparison result not show on pictureBox1]

The code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CompositeDifferences
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap m_referenceImage = null;
        private Bitmap m_seocondImage = null;
        private Bitmap m_thirdImage = null;
        private Bitmap m_resultImage = null;

        Rectangle rect;
        bool painting = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        private int m_tolerance = 120;
        private int m_radarRadius = 256;
        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            m_referenceImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"d:\Comparison\radar_without_clouds.jpg");
            m_seocondImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"d:\Comparison\ConvertedBmp.bmp");
            m_thirdImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"d:\Comparison\radar666.bmp");
            m_resultImage = (Bitmap)m_referenceImage.Clone();

            pictureBox1.Image = m_referenceImage;
            pictureBox2.Image = m_seocondImage;
            pictureBox3.Image = m_thirdImage;
        }
        
        private unsafe void CompositeDifferences(Bitmap referenceImage, Bitmap otherImage, Bitmap resultImage, int radarRadius, double tolerance)
        {
            if (referenceImage.Width != otherImage.Width && referenceImage.Height != otherImage.Height)
                return;
            int width = referenceImage.Width;
            int height = referenceImage.Height;

            int widthRect = rect.Width;
            int heightRect = rect.Height;

            BitmapData referenceImageData = referenceImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, referenceImage.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData otherImageData = otherImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, otherImage.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData resultImageData = resultImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, resultImage.PixelFormat);

            int referenceStride = referenceImageData.Stride;
            int otherStride = otherImageData.Stride;
            int resultStride = resultImageData.Stride;

            byte* referenceScan0 = (byte*)referenceImageData.Scan0;
            byte* otherScan0 = (byte*)otherImageData.Scan0;
            byte* resultScan0 = (byte*)resultImageData.Scan0;

            int referenceBytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(referenceImage.PixelFormat) / 8;
            int otherBytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(otherImage.PixelFormat) / 8;
            int resultBytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(resultImage.PixelFormat) / 8;

            for (int y = 0; y < /*height*/ heightRect; y++)
            {
                byte* referenceCurrentRow = referenceScan0 + y * referenceStride;
                byte* otherCurrentRow = otherScan0 + y * otherStride;
                byte* resultCurrentRow = resultScan0 + y * resultStride;
                for (int x = 0; x < /*width*/ widthRect; x++)
                {
                    if (!IsInsideCircle(x, y, width / 2, height / 2, radarRadius))
                        continue;
                    ColorBgr* referencePixel = (ColorBgr*)(referenceCurrentRow + x * referenceBytesPerPixel);
                    ColorBgr* otherPixel = (ColorBgr*)(otherCurrentRow + x * otherBytesPerPixel);
                    ColorBgr* resultPixel = (ColorBgr*)(resultCurrentRow + x * resultBytesPerPixel);
                    if (referencePixel->GetDistanceSquared(*otherPixel) >= tolerance * tolerance)
                        *resultPixel = *otherPixel;
                }
            }

            referenceImage.UnlockBits(referenceImageData);
            otherImage.UnlockBits(otherImageData);
            resultImage.UnlockBits(resultImageData);
        }
        private bool IsInsideCircle(Point p, Point center, int radius)
        {
            int dx = p.X - center.X;
            int dy = p.Y - center.Y;

            return dx * dx + dy * dy <= radius * radius;
        }
        private bool IsInsideCircle(int x, int y, int centerX, int centerY, int radius)
        {
            return IsInsideCircle(new Point(x, y), new Point(centerX, centerY), radius);
        }
        private void ProcessChanges()
        {
            CompositeDifferences(m_referenceImage, m_seocondImage, m_resultImage, m_radarRadius, m_tolerance);
            CompositeDifferences(m_referenceImage, m_thirdImage, m_resultImage, m_radarRadius, m_tolerance);
            pictureBox1.Image = m_resultImage;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_tolerance = trackBar1.Value;
            ProcessChanges();
        }

        private void trackBar2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_radarRadius = trackBar1.Value;
            ProcessChanges();
        }

        private struct ColorBgr : IEquatable<ColorBgr>
        {
            public byte B;
            public byte G;
            public byte R;
            public ColorBgr(byte b, byte g, byte r)
            {
                B = b;
                G = g;
                R = r;
            }
            public double GetDistanceSquared(ColorBgr other)
            {
                double db = other.B - B;
                double dg = other.G - G;
                double dr = other.R - R;
                return db * db + dg * dg + dr * dr;
            }
            public static bool operator ==(ColorBgr left, ColorBgr right)
            {
                return left.Equals(right);
            }
            public static bool operator !=(ColorBgr left, ColorBgr right)
            {
                return !(left == right);
            }
            public bool Equals(ColorBgr other)
            {
                return this.B == other.B && this.G == other.G && this.R == other.R;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj is ColorBgr)
                    return Equals((ColorBgr)obj);
                return false;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return new byte[] { B, G, R }.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
            painting = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, Math.Min(e.X - rect.Left, pictureBox2.ClientRectangle.Width - rect.Left), Math.Min(e.Y - rect.Top, pictureBox2.ClientRectangle.Height - rect.Top));
            }
            this.pictureBox2.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessChanges();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (painting == true)
            {
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had only a look of 5 sec on your code, but, do you think, that the formular in   private bool IsInsideCircle(Point p, Point center, int radius)
      is correct ? You tested it with unit tests ?

Comment: @nobody yeah, you are right. That part belongs to my answer. It should be surrounded with paranthesis. `(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= (radius * radius)`

Comment: if my math knowlege will me not blame, the paranthesis doesn't metter in this case, because the expressions allready seperated by the comparison operator "<=" itself. But the squareProduct of the coordindate distances (possible wrong calculated) in relation to the diameter of the cycle ? Do you think that this will result in what he want ?

Comment: @johnlast All you need is to adjust the loop ranges.

Comment: No, you can compare the distance between two points by taking square. It doesn't change the result. It is just an optimization.

Comment: @johnlast You don't change the start of the loops. They still start from zero.

Comment: @jtxkopt i changed the loops start but still when drawing the rectangle on the small pictureBox2 it's not showing the differents clouds ion the big pictureBox1 it's not doing the comparison between the two pictureBoxes 2 and 3 or maybe it does but not showing the compared rectangle part on teh pictureBox1.  the first loop : for (int y = rect.Y; y < heightRect; y++) and the inner loop : for (int x = rect.X; x < widthRect; x++)

Comment: @jtxkopt i'm using the widthRect and heightRect variables only on the loops.

Comment: @jhonlast The rectangle you draw is in the stretched image's coordinate system. That means you should scale the rectangle accordingly. So, for example, if your scaled image has a size of `(150, 200)`, you also must scale the rectangle by a factor of `(512/150, 512/200)` before using it in proccessing method.

Comment: @jhonlast And when you determine the processing area with a rectangle, you don't need to check if it is in the circle anymore.

Comment: @jtxkopt in the pictureBox2 mouse up event before making the proccessing if i'm scaling the rectangle it's just making the rectanlge very small on pictureBox2.  private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            rect.Width = 512 / 150;
            rect.Height = 512 / 150;

            ProcessChanges();
        }